# How to delete recent post published by facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am auto posting on user wall with php now i want to put a link or button to allow user to delete recent post published by application please help me for it

Comment: i am using PHP ............

Comment: are you trying to perform the delete API call through javascript or php?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete something by making POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete` Check out the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/ and let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: in response i am getting post id here is code  'if (response && response.post_id) {
     alert('Post was not published.');
  } else {
   
 alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);'  now for delete i can sent post request which need access token and post id how i can make a url with using this post id